# Path to Application Package

Tags: java, android, path, io, package

I only have focused on making apps for apps that will be installed on the phone memory.

Is there any way to know dynamically the path of the application package (Environment.get...? or some other flag that can be used)? My concern is if you restore a database you must provide a destination path. That would be different depending on where the application is (sd card versus internal memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get the location of the classpath, or of the location of a class itself (classpath + package path)?

To get the location of the classpath, you can do the following:

```
    String location = Boot.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
    location = URLDecoder.decode(location, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Boot would be replaced with any class.

Comment: I am trying to get the directory that my program is installed in dynamically versus statically coding it. Does that make sense?

Comment: I believe so, and that piece of code get's the classpath of your application dynamically.  The only static part of it is the Boot.class, which can be replaced with any class, or even could be replaced with getClass().  My Boot class is the main class of my jar application, and it needs to locate the jar so it can dynamically configure the boot to run the jar with required libraries and options.  This locating of your application's directory is not what you are trying to do?

Comment: Vulcan- I just found what I was looking for. In the android documentation it mentions that the program files still reside on  internal memory under data/data/package. Therefore, my database will go to the same location as it would normally. http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html